# firejail: child-process not sandboxed?

Tags: sandbox, firejail, calibre

As far as the sandbox **"firejail"** is concerned I´ve encountered a phenomenon which isn´t completely clear to me.

My understanding has always been that whenever I start a programm/process in **firejail** that process is sandboxed.
Fine, that´s clear.

I was also of the opinion that whenever that sandboxed process triggers another process that one is by default sandboxed, too.

This is the case e.g. when doing this:
*`"firejail thunderbird"`* and then clicking on a link within a mail.

So (in my case) **firefox**, which
is my default browser, opens up and displays the website the link is referring to. Plus: *firefox is sandboxed, too*. I think this is
what it should be like.

But:
whenever I statrt **calibre** with *`"firejail calibre"`*, that one is sandboxed. O.K. That´s fine too.

Now for the tricky part: When trying to open a pdf-file within the sandoxed calibre my default pdf-reader (**evince**) fires up but ***isn´t sandboxed***.

*`"firejail --tree"`* doesn´t list it, nor does **firetools**. 
I also can shutdown calibre and evince (displaying) the pdf-file remains open.

Can you tell me anything about that phenomenon?

Tnx a lot in advance.

Rosika